# Run Vasco OTP exe from java and get the generate OTP used in my application

Tags: java, testing, web-applications

I am writing automated test cases for my web application using TESTNG, My web application requires user to input OTP on the second page of application, while automating the same using TESTNG i didn't find approach of how to read the OTP generated and pass it to my test case.

I am able to open the Vasco OTP using Java runtime class, but after that i need to pass the serial number and then click on Generate button to get the OTP generated which is later required to be passed to my web application.